# How to easily add library to PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, is there any way to add a GitHub library directly like the PyCharm or we have to clone the library and put some files in the file directory ?

Comment: Have you looked at [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)? It basically is the package manager of php (like pip for python). PyCharm does nothing else than calling pip if you install a package using the gui.

Comment: Thank you! I look it now and that is what i need :)